# Require('child_process') => cannot find Require / child_process + launch .bat

Tags: angularjs, node.js, require, child-process

It has been 3 days I'm searching on forums a way to make work my program, and it still doesn’t work…

I'm working on **my first AngularJS project**, and I need to **launch an external program** when the user clicks on an image.

I have a module named tool-list, and in my tool-list.component.ts, I export a class named ToolListComponent.
In this class I have my function to launch my external program.

```
    launchtool(){
      alert("I'm trying to launch test.bat!");
      const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
      //const bat = spawn('start', ['./TrashCode/test.bat']);
      //const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['start', './TrashCode/test.bat']);
      //var exec = child_process.spawn('start', './TrashCode/test.bat', {detached: true});
      alert("It works!");
    }
```

**In commented I keep a few line I tried.**

My problem: When I use **require** => **error TS2304 cannot find name 'require'.**
Or just **child_process** => **error cannot find module 'child_process'.**

I'm definitly not the first who has this kind of problem, but neither of the solution worked for me (import, import * as, require, declare function require(name:string), var require: any; [...]).

Maybe the solution is evident for some of you; I'm reviewing my lessons in this case.

**Server and Client will be on the client side, Im just using web as an HMI**

Comment: Do you want the child_process to run on the client or server side?
child_process and require are part of node.js, but not of the client.

Comment: Either of them will be on the client.
I know this so I want to launch the program with the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run a child process through a web browser, unless your app is running in a desktop app container such as [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) (which makes Node modules available within its web runtime). It would be horrendously insecure to allow browsers to execute shell scripts - imagine if a pop-up was able to download a `.bat` and immediately run it on your machine...

That said, if you want the batch file to run *on the server* and just be triggered by the client, that's perfectly feasible - just call `child_process.spawn()` in response to a REST call of some kind.

Comment: @Ryusekai - Your best bet then would be to use something like Express to create a simple REST API with a route handler that contains code to spawn the child process. You can then use Angular's built-in `$http` service to remotely call that API from your app.

Comment: Yes of course! I forgot to precise that I wanted to launch it from the server side.
You mean I was trying to launch it in the Client side?

=> I will check what is Express, but I didn't choose to use AngluarJS

Comment: @Ryusekai - If it's part of your Angular app/is running in the browser, that's client side, yes. The `require` function and the `child_process` module itself are part of Node.js, not the standard JavaScript spec, and as such you can't natively use them in the browser.

Comment: Mmmh, it makes sense!
Can I ask you one more thing?
How do I do the difference between the Client and the Server in my file?

Comment: @Ryusekai - I'm not sure exactly what you mean? As in, the file structure?

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to look at your answer.
Yes that's was my question, I'll continue to read tutorials to have the answer but I have understood that typeScrit (.ts) when transpiled (?) in JavaScript is executed on the client side.