# Is there a way to make CLI commands from AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, webpack, cmd

I have created a service to make some CLI/terminal commands from my AngularJS controller using `child-process` but it seems like I am unable to do that. Following is my service:

**listFiles.js:**

```
'use strict'
var exec = require('child_process').exec;


const listFiles = function(){
    exec('ls', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        // node couldn't execute the command
        return;
      }

      // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
    });
}

export default listFiles;
```

I have also added the following to my package.json:

```
"browser": { 
    "fs": false, 
    "child_process": false 
  },
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: exec is not a function

I am using webpack to build the application. Is there a way to make CLI commands in AngularJS controller/or as a AngularJS service?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the following question:

[Angularjs - Require('child_process')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721793/requirechild-process-cannot-find-require-child-process-launch-bat)

To sum it up: You cannot run child processes through a browser application as this would be a huge security issue.

If you want to run some command on your server, write a REST API using NodeJS or any other server technology and call it from your AngularJS application.

UPDATE:

Here's a simple example of how to use express to handle a HTTP GET request.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const command = req.query. command // Get the command form the query parameters.
    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO USING child_process

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port 3000');
});
```

You can find different examples in the official [ExpressJs documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app).

Comment: Any insights on how can I write this using express? I have a server that uses expressjs to define the middleware.